# Using iterated rows in Python with dates

Tags: python, pandas, loops, time-series

I have a timeseries dataset that I need to create multiple correlation matrices for different date subsets.  I'm trying to create a loop but can't get it to work.  I have the main dataframe, data, with

```
1-1-1990
...
1-30-1990
```

and have created a separate dataframe, df2, with 2 columns for the begin and end for each week (so 4 rows.  The real data is longer but this is an example of what I'm trying to do).

I can get it to loop through the rows of df2 with itertuples() easily enough but get an error when I try to use those dates to parse the main dataframe, such as

```
for ir in df2.itertuples():
    df = data.loc['ir(begin)': 'ir(end)']
```

telling me "Unknown datatime string format, unable to parse: ir[begin]".

I'm new to Python so I'm sure there are much better ways to accomplish this.  In SAS I would have just made a macro calling each macro(begin, end).  If anyone has any suggestions I really appreciate it.  Thank you.

Comment: What is the last results on df?

Comment: From the code I have there?  None, since it gives the error.  It should read df = data.loc[1-1-1990: 1-7-1990] and then update to a new week for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you try

```
For index, line in df2.iterrows():
```

Maybe helpful link:
https://medium.com/swlh/why-pandas-itertuples-is-faster-than-iterrows-and-how-to-make-it-even-faster-bc50c0edd30d

Comment: Thanks.  The issue isn't so much the loop but getting the results to work for loc.  The original data has the dates as indexes, I'm just trying to figure out how to set up a loop/macro that will allow me to parse the data by week/set amount of days.  My question involving the loop is how to get results that will work in the data.loc, whether it's iterrows or itertuples or something else, I don't know.